# Can OMXPlayer show SRT subtitles embedded in a mp4 file?

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, srt, omxplayer, video-subtitles

Is there a way to get OMXPlayer to show the embedded subtitles in foo.mp4 without first extracting the subtitles with ffmpeg to foo.srt, and without hardcoding the subtitles into foo.mp4?

Comment: MP4 only supports "mov_text" subtitles. Are you sure OMXPlayer can read that format?

Comment: Yes,  omxplayer --subtitles foo.srt foo.mp4    displays subtitles.

Comment: That's SRT. I was asking about the alleged embedded subtitles in the MP4 itself.

Comment: ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 \
-f srt -i subtitle.srt \
-c:a copy -c:v copy -c:s \
mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 \
language=nor \
-movflags +faststart \
outfile.mp4

Comment: VLC displays the subtitles,omxplayer outfile.mp4 does not.

Comment: If you want to use omxplayer it appears you are stuck using SRT and will not be able to avoid the extra step of extracting.

Comment: Could MKV solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding SRT subtitles to a MKV-container instead of MP4:

```
ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 \
-f srt -i subtitles.srt \
-c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s srt \
-metadata:s:s:0 language=nor \
outfile.mkv
```

Subtitles can than be displayed by starting OMXPlayer with -t 0

```
omxplayer -t 0 outfile.mkv
```